# How to check if in crosshair cursor mode

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

I need to display additional information with the crosshair.
Is there a way to detect when the user switched to crosshair mode and use the mouse position info to draw some text that follows the cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No direct controls of built-in Terminal GUI
in MQL5 programming environment

Well, MQL4/5 has no direct control over the MetaTrader Terminal 5 built-in GUI elements and their MMI-state ( the cursor state, the less to switch it on/off ). That was never available to the code-execution engine.

---

### How to add it?

If in a need to have such functionality, one may create one's own GUI-layer and simulate a cross-hair functionality ( altogether with any additional add-on-s ) without waiting for GUI interaction with a built-in cross-hair button. This was possible many years back, even in the original MQL4 code.

So the need is definitely doable in MQL5 code.